# How to save a copy of a Jupyter notebook open in a browser after losing connection to the kernel?

Tags: python, google-chrome, ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter notebook opened in my browser, that connects to a kernel in a remote server. I lost connection to the remote server and cannot connect again.

How can I save a local copy of the .ipynb file of this in browser notebook?

Comment: From my experience, once a connection is lost, you can't save or download the notebook, but if the notebook you were working on is already saved in your directory then it can be accessed again through Jupyter (meaning start Jupyter from Anaconda Navigator) and then select your desired notebook from folders list. Often notebook autosave latest edits made. -Hope this helps.

Comment: @personaltest25 This sound pretty bad for my situation. There are changes not saved to the server yet. More problematic is that the server is down indefinitely and I need to get the notebook out.

Comment: Update, I could retrieve the notebook from the server in the end. The lesson is to not trust autosaving too much and press the save button yourself.

Comment: Besides, the html source of the open notebook actually contains all the cells' code and output. So it's technically feasible to convert that html source to a .ipynb. Fortunately, I don't have to go that route.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I was worried for you. That is a good lesson, which I personally need to keep in mind. -Thank you for the update!